# jQuery height() not changing on resize

Tags: jquery, resize, height

I never had this problem before but I can't seem to find the solution, so I hope you guys can help me out.

**jQuery**

```
function setTheHeight() {

    if( $('#main.level1 .block.attention .block-content').length ) {
        //Get value of highest element
        var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, $('#main.level1 .block.attention .block-content').map (
            function() {
                return $(this).height();
            }
        ));
        console.log(maxHeight);
        $('#main.level1 .block.attention .block-content').height(maxHeight);
    }
}

setTheHeight();

$(window).resize(function() {
    setTheHeight();
});
```

Basicly what this function does is check for the highest div and set the height of all selected div's to this height. This works fine. BUT it's a responsive design so when the user resize's his browser the content gets smaller and the div higher. So i added a resize event. The event is being fired but it's not changing the height. Any idea's why the resize is not changing the height?

Quick jsFiddle to show what happens: http://jsfiddle.net/3mVkn/

**FIX**

Hmm this was just plain stupid. Because I was setting the height() it was already fixed so all I had to do is just reset the height and it worked.

Updated code:

```
function setTheHeight() {

    if( $('#main.level1 .block.attention .block-content').length ) {

        //Reset height
        $('#main.level1 .block.attention .block-content').height('auto');

        //Get value of highest element
        var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(Math, $('#main.level1 .block.attention .block-content').map (
            function() {
                return $(this).height();
            }
        ));
        console.log(maxHeight);
        $('#main.level1 .block.attention .block-content').height(maxHeight);
    }
}

setTheHeight();

$(window).resize(function() {
    setTheHeight();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not jQuery related but CSS. It is because once you have set the height of the .block-content to some value, after you resize the window the heights of those .block-content wont change because the heights are no longer set to `auto` but to some predefined value.

The solution is to use `return $(this)[0].scrollHeight` instead of `return $(this).height()`
This way it will return the real height of the content, not the CSS defined height.

**EDIT:**

The solution is actually to calculate the height of all children inside the .block-content and then return that value. I've edited your code here http://jsfiddle.net/3mVkn/12/

This should give you the result needed.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for your response. Unfortunately this didn't seem to fix the probleem :(

Comment: Yes, you are right. Please check the edit, I've supplied the correct solution now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing one parameter of `.map()` function. I looked `.map()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/).