# JQuery animate element height after changing content

Tags: jquery

I want to resize a div element automaticly after Ajax data was loaded into it.
So far I've no problems in making it taller with that

```
success: function (data) {
              var oldSize = $("#DivPreview").height();
              $("#DivPreview").html(data.d);
              var newSize = $("#DivPreview").height();
              $("#DivPreview").height(oldSize).animate({ height: newSize });
}
```

But that only works the first time, after that `oldSize`and    `newSize`are the same not matter what and it doesn't make the `div`smaller
 Does anybody know how I can change the `Height`property dynamically in a smooth way?
If that is useful for you to know I want to create some kind of preview/suggestion for new topics just like on this page when you want to create a new question the `"Questions that may already have your answer"`Box
Thank your for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scrollHeight` instead. `Height()` sets the css value and is therefore not updated the second time. Since height is set on the parent, you need to calculate the size of the contents instead.

```js
function resizeDiv (elements) {
  // This will actually just get the css value (which was set last time)
  var oldSize = $("#DivPreview").height();
  $("#DivPreview").html(elements);
  // Since height is already set, we calculate the size of the contents instead.
  var newSize = $("#DivPreview ul")[0].scrollHeight;
  $("#DivPreview").height(oldSize).animate({ height: newSize });
}

$('#DivLong, #DivShort').click(function(){
  var $el = $(this).html();
  resizeDiv($el);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="DivPreview">
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>  
</div>

<div id="DivShort">
<ul>
  <li>One (click me)</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ul>  
</div>

<div id="DivLong">
<ul>
  <li>One (click me)</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Siz</li>
  <li>Seven</li>
  <li>Eight</li>
  <li>Nine</li>
</ul>  
</div>
```

See answer below for more info.

[jQuery height() not changing on resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11559534/jquery-height-not-changing-on-resize)

Comment: thank you very much. When I first click on `DivShort` it becomes smaller but it still stays at the same size when I click on `DivShort` after I clicked on `DivLong`. Do you understand what I'm trying to say? sry for bad english^^"

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand. Are you trying the snippet above? First, click on DivShort, then click on DivLong. It should adjust to the size of the last clicked div.

Comment: Yes it does... but when You click on DivShort again it stays tall and does not become small again. I just found another solution... when I use `$("#DivPreview").removeAttr('style');` at the start of the function everything works quite well

Comment: Yes, but then you might loose the animation.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to put `oldSize` in a global variable or put it in a `$.data` of `#DivPreview` in following way so that it persists all over the time:

```
success: function (data) {

    var oldSize = $("#DivPreview").data("oldSize") != null ? $("#DivPreview").data("oldSize") : $("#DivPreview").height();
    $("#DivPreview").data("oldSize", oldSize);

    $("#DivPreview").html(data.d);
    var newSize = $("#DivPreview").height();
    $("#DivPreview").height(oldSize).animate({ height: newSize });
}
```